# How to improve score when having a exact match in a list on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm pretty new to elastic search, I'm having this issue below.

Having these two records:

```json
    POST test/_doc/1
    {
      "id": 1,
      "authors": [
        {
          "name": "Test Name",
          "url": "/url/1/"
        }
      ]
    }

    POST test/_doc/2
    {
      "id": 2,
      "authors": [
        {
          "name": "Test Name",
          "url": "/url/1/"
        },
            {
          "name": "Another author",
          "url": "/url/another/"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And this query:

```json
    GET test/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "authors.name": {
                      "_name": "exact match in authors",
                      "query": "Test Name",
                      "boost": 100,
                      "slop": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Why the score is lower when having multiple authors? And how can I make it higher or the same value as the record that have only one author?

```json
    {
      ...
      "hits": {
        "max_score": 42.221836,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_score": 42.221836,
            "_source": {
              "id": 1,
              "authors": [
                {
                  "name": "Test Name",
                  "url": "/url/1/"
                }
              ]
            },
            "matched_queries": [
              "exact match in authors"
            ]
          },
          {
            "_score": 32.088596,
            "_source": {
              "id": 2,
              "authors": [
                {
                  "name": "Test Name",
                  "url": "/url/1/"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Another author",
                  "url": "/url/another/"
                }
              ]
            },
            "matched_queries": [
              "exact match in authors"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I can't find anything on the docs about this.

The following details are just to make sure stackoverflow don't show the following error:
`It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried @paulo solution, but it didn't fully work for me, so I ended up adding a nested field:

```json
      "authors": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

And used this query:

```json
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "authors",
        "_name": "exact match in authors",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "authors.name": {
                            "query": "Test Name",
                            "boost": 100,
                            "slop": 1,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Elastic search doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

After these changes, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR;

It is because your 2nd documents has a longer field.
You may wont to look into:

- constant scoring
- filter
- function scoring

## To understand

What do I mean by that ?

Elasticsearch when dealing with an array of document is going to store them like so:

Initially:

```json
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "A0"
    },
        {
      "name": "A1"
    }
  ]
}
```

To :

```json
{
  "authors.name": ["A0", "A1"]
}
```

And the document score are computed using TF/IDF.
But TF is relative to the length of the document.

- Doc 1 `authors.name` is of length 2
- Doc 2 `authors.name` is of length 4

## To investigate:

You could use the [API _explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html):

```json
GET 77469343/_explain/1
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "authors.name": {
              "_name": "exact match in authors",
              "query": "Test Name",
              "boost": 100,
              "slop": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which should give you the following results:

#### doc 1

```json
{
  "_index": "77469343",
  "_id": "1",
  "matched": true,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 42.221836,
    "description": """weight(authors.name:"test name"~1 in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:""",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 42.221836,
        "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 220,
            "description": "boost",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 0.36464313,
            "description": "idf, sum of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 0.18232156,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 0.18232156,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": 0.5263158,
            "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 1,
                "description": "phraseFreq=1.0",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 1.2,
                "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 0.75,
                "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 2,
                "description": "dl, length of field",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 3,
                "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                "details": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### doc 2

```json
{
  "_index": "77469343",
  "_id": "2",
  "matched": true,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 32.088596,
    "description": """weight(authors.name:"test name"~1 in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:""",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 32.088596,
        "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 220,
            "description": "boost",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 0.36464313,
            "description": "idf, sum of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 0.18232156,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 0.18232156,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 2,
                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": 0.40000004,
            "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 1,
                "description": "phraseFreq=1.0",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 1.2,
                "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 0.75,
                "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 4,
                "description": "dl, length of field",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 3,
                "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                "details": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## To Fix

#### Constant scoring

You may want to look into the `constant_score` query, if you still want a score:

```json
GET 77469343/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "authors.name": {
                  "_name": "exact match in authors",
                  "query": "Test Name",
                  "boost": 100,
                  "slop": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 1.2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Filter instead of should ?

If you use filter, matching document won't interfere with the score:

```json
GET 77469343/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "authors.name": {
              "_name": "exact match in authors",
              "query": "Test Name",
              "boost": 100,
              "slop": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, Do you know how can I get the same score in both records?

Comment: I have updated the answer with some pointers